# Sum extra credit

Tags: python, list, loops, sum

Stuck at an issue during an exercise.

> Assign sum_extra with the total extra credit received given list
> test_grades. Full credit is 100, so anything over 100 is extra credit.

What I've arranged.

```
for i in test_grades:
     if i > 100:
        sum_extra.append(i - 100)

sum_extra = sum(sum_extra)
```

The error I've received.

```
Exited with return code 1.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    sum_extra.append(i - 100)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Not completely sure what's causing it since the list generated by the exercise should be in integer form. In my head this should work, but that's surely due to not understanding some key element here.

Full view.

```
user_input = input()
test_grades = list(map(int, user_input.split())) # test_grades is an integer list of test scores

sum_extra = -999 # Initialize 0 before your loop

for i in test_grades:
     if i > 100:
        sum_extra.append(i - 100)

sum_extra = sum(sum_extra)
```

Expected output would be a sum of a generated list from test_grades input.

Comment: error is clear: `sum_extra` is initialized as integer, and you're appending to it... just `sum_extra += i - 100` probably

Comment: `sum()` takes a list. If you want to add to an integer, use `sum_extra += i - 100`... Also `-999` is not "initialize 0"

Comment: Thanks Jean, I realize this may be obvious to you this is however the very first programming course I've taken so it is not in fact obvious to me.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you have a number. `.append` is only a valid operation for lists.

---

You can use a generator expression instead, and pass this to `sum()`

"Take the sum of (each number minus 100) from `test_grades` if that number is over 100"

```
sum_extra = sum(i - 100 for i in test_grades if i > 100)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
user_input = input()
test_grades = list(map(int, user_input.split())) # test_grades is an integer list of test scores


sum_extra = 0 # Initialize 0 before your loop

for grade in test_grades:
    if grade > 100:
        sum_extra += (grade - 100)
        
print('Sum extra:', sum_extra)
```